# How do I change the font size of the legend in a seaborn catplot

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot

I am trying to increase the font size of the legend of a catplot.

The data:

```
Status  SameDay     Pickup point    Trip Completed
0   False   Airport     60
1   False   City    38
2   True    Airport     1267
3   True    City    1466
```

My code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=[20,10])
sns.set_theme(style="whitegrid")
res = sns.catplot(data=sameday_trips,kind="bar",x="SameDay",y="Trip Completed",hue="Pickup point",
            palette="dark", alpha=.6, height=6)
res.despine(left=True)
res.set_xlabels("SameDay Trip?",fontsize=20)
res.set_ylabels("Trips Completed",fontsize=20)
res.set_xticklabels(fontsize=20)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
res.set_yticklabels(fontsize=20)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the similar posts on this query!!!!